# No object found in the last part of the sentence, is it grammatical?

Tags: meaning, grammar, objects

> Pile them in the frozen-food cabinets with the juice, **and** **there was breakfast ready, oven-fresh,** from the east coast to the west.

I am confused about the bold part from an [article](http://www.economist.com/node/21552989) which talks about bagels, since "breakfast ready", "oven fresh" are adjectives and no object is found here.

Is the object omitted in the sentence (which sounds a little bit weird to me as a non-native speaker)? Are there any guidelines teaching English learners writing sentence like one?

Answer (score 1):

> Pile them in the frozen-food cabinets with the juice, **and** **there was breakfast ready, oven-fresh,** from the east coast to the west.

There is no omitted noun. What you have is the noun *breakfast* with post-modifiers. That is, the adjectives *ready” and “oven-fresh” modify *breakfast*.

> breakfast ready, oven-fresh

is equivalent to

> ready, oven-fresh breakfast

It’s clear that breakfast here consists of both *juice* and *them* (*bagels*), so the adjectives modify *breakfast* not a proposed omitted *bagels*.

Still, the sentence is awkward and awkwardly punctuated. It’s possible the writer constructed the sentence so that the near-rhyming words *freah* and *west* each ended a phrase.

Comment: Just a heads up that I've updated the wording of the question a little bit.